# display details of employees who joined in first march of each year

Tags: sql, oracle

In my Oracle database I have a table `employees` with thousand of records.
It has columns:

1. `employee_id`
2. `first_name`
3. `last_name`
4. `email`
5. `salary`
6. `hire_date`

I want to show employees who joined in each year with a `hire_date` on the `23`th day of month `March`.

However, when using below SELECT statement it shows only empty records.

```sql
SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE to_char(hire_date, 'mon')='dec'
   AND to_char(hire_date, 'DD')='23';
```

tryng to display a records but it is no showing.what should be  aproper format for displaing date and month of particular records.

Comment: I have tried this but it is not showing results.it shows blank records.

Comment: 1) "Blank records" doesn't help any more than "empty records" - are there results or not? 2) Your text mentions **March**, but your query mentions **dec**. 3) Are you sure there are rows in the table which *should* match this query?

Comment:  Please fix your question: (a) either `first march` as in title, or (b) `23 March` as in text, or else (c) `23 december`  as in SQL. Take this as training: Consistency and focus will help you as developer-attitude in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your question you say you are looking for employees on the 23rd of March, but in the where clause of your example query, you are searching for employees hired on the 23rd of December.

To prevent any differentiating spellings of months in different languages and compare using one filter in your where clause instead of two, you can use a query like this one.

```sql
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL
  FROM EMPLOYEES
 WHERE TO_CHAR (hire_date, 'MMDD') = '0323';
```

Comment: (to_char(hire_date , 'mmdd'='0323'; works

Answer (score 1):

ANSI/ISO SQL solution is `EXTRACT()`:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE extract(day from hire_date) = 23
  AND extract(month from hire_date) = 3
```

Comment: Fun-fact and docs: Oracle's [`EXTRACT(datetime)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html#GUID-36E52BF8-945D-437D-9A3C-6860CABD210E) docs have an example using table employees with hire_date 

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's [`to_char`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) function is applied correctly using the column `hire_date` of type `DATE` as argument with [formats models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510) `DD` for *day-of-month*.

By the way, this function with most of the format-literals (at least `DD` and `MON`) is also supported by PostgreSQL and MySQL.

### Possible Issues: with the abbreviated month-name

I wonder if `mon` for *month abbreviated name* works correctly.
At least the right-hand side of month is an issue because lowercase `dec` instead uppercase `DEC`. Also pay attention to the *locale* used to format month-names. In English locales `DEC` for `December` should work.

For the month of `March` as stated in your question, you would use `'MAR'` as right-hand side of the month-comparison (not `DEC`).

### Simplification

Simpler is to use combined format like `TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DD-MON') = '23-DEC'` respectively using the month-abbreviation in your database-locale.

#### Test using group-by with count

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DD-MON') as hired_day, COUNT(*)
FROM employees
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DD-MON')
WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DD') = '23'
```

Should return the day and month (formatted in your locale) with a count of hired employees - restricted to the 23th for all months recorded (max 12 rows in result-set).

You can also omit the last line with `WHERE` condition to get all days, resulting in a longer list.